# Keyboard types by itself

Tags: keyboard

I'm helping my sister and here is the issue she told me about:

When she puts the typing marker in a typing bar (i.e Google search bar) it automatically starts to type a certain key (to be exact "s") in a sequence. It doesn't stop no matter what. If typing option is available that's what happens.

Any one familiar with that issue? Is it a virus? For now I recommended her to check the keyboard circuit and to clean it (that recommendation I took from here about a bit different problem involving similar properties).

Thanks ahead

Comment: Unplug the keyboard while it's occurring. If it stops, change to a new keyboard. Of course, you can't do this in the case of a built-in keyboard, where you'd have to send the laptop for repairs.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is a rather vague question from the standpoint of the type of computer you are referring to, the operating system and when the problem started. If you could [edit] your question to include more details would improve this question, we might be able to give you more specific answers. At this point, all we can do is guess.

Comment: `I recommended her to check the keyboard circuit and to clean it` - Really? How do you propose that she'll `clean the circuit`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what kind of device you have. This answer is good for a personal computer, but not a tablet or smartphone...

You need to determine if it is a hardware (keyboard) problem or a software (virus) problem.

If this system has a removeable keyboard, disconnect it and see if the problem goes away. If it does, it will probably be easier to replace the keyboard rather than repair it.

Another way to troubleshoot this is to temporarily boot into Linux, and seeing if the problem persists. Linux won't use any existing files, drivers, or viruses(!) from your primary operating system.

If you have a CD drive, then the easiest way to do this is to download and burn a copy of Linux onto a CD, and boot from that disc. Then, after determining if the problem has gone away, you can shut down Linux, remove the cd, and boot back into your existing operating system.

If you haven't done this before, [Ubuntu Linux](http://www.ubuntu.com) is one user-friendly option.